# No "webform" link in operations column

Tags: 7, webforms

i'm new to Drupal and PHP in general, so this may be obvious - But I'm working with Drupal 7 with module webform installed. Recently, i don't know why the link stopped appearing in the Operations column on the Content list page in the admin.
 Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: try to change your theme and then try

Comment: i try it :/ but it does'nt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi make sure you are enable the webform functionality  like this 
check 
http://prntscr.com/bur06a
 if not working then  follow  tutorial

Comment: i didn' find it, [link](http://prntscr.com/bur3mf)

Comment: try  with new webform   go to admin/content  add new / webform

Comment: i found the same thing :/

Comment: give me  your  site link

Comment: it's just local

Comment: ok  have you follow this https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/webform-module/

Comment: i have alredy creating my webform with differents fields and some conditions and it works fine but today i was surprising when i didn't find the link operation webform :/

Comment: check this  https://www.drupal.org/node/1161924  your problem is same

Comment: finaly it's work, i follow the first tutoriel, you was right, enable webform was uncecked :$ thank you so much for your help

Comment: my pleasure buddy keep codeing